# Retrieving information from a site using python

Tags: python

I am some what new to python and retrieving data from an online source in general.

I am wondering if I am able to use this data, http://www.metlink.org.nz/timetables/train/HVL to make a travel route application which needs a to and from location, and gets the closest times.

If so, what library should I learn? If not, do you have another example I could learn on?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: You should learn the standard library. Well, not each detail though. Start with learning what it has in it.

Comment: Are there any good tutorials you could link me to ?

Comment: Start with http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/urllib2.html

Comment: look at urllib and beautifulsoup. http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, so what I am wanting to do should be an ok example to learn on?

Comment: @user2469515 It’s a good example, practical and reasonably sized. Except that you’ll have to deal with HTML; if you’re not familiar with it, you might find the data extraction (scraping) part something of a chore.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into `urllib`. It is built into Python and is great for parsing websites. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GzVNi0oTxQ) is a good tutorial to get you started.  Hope this helps!